# Isomorphism of Principal G-Bundles and Hom($\pi_1(X)$,G)/G

Tags: algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, principal-bundles, cobordism

I'm reading [this paper](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/reine/u/ulrich.pennig/slides/2D-TQFT.pdf) and I am trying to wrap my head around the bijection found on the bottom of page 2, namely

> $$\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1 (X),G)/G\xrightarrow{\sim}
>  \operatorname{Prin}_G(X)$$

Where $G$ is a discrete group.  This is how I see it:  An element $\alpha\in \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1 (X),G)$ is sent to a fiber in $ \operatorname{Prin}_G(X)$.  Since $G$ acts freely, each $\alpha$ represents an automorphism of $G$.  Modding out by $G$ indicates we should regard each of these fibers (or automorphisms of $G$) in  $ \operatorname{Prin}_G(X)$ as the same.  How far off am I in my understanding?

Comment: Principal $G$ bundles are classified by maps into $BG$. But $BG$ is a quotient of a contractible space by a free action. Since $G$ is discrete, one sees that $\pi_1(BG)=G$ and all other homotopy groups vanish. Thus we see that $BG$ is a $K(G,1)$. But maps into $K(G,1)$ are exactly the same thing as cohomology classes of degree $1$. So principal $G$ bundles are in one to one correspondence with $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})=\hom(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z})$. One can probably do algebra to get the correspondence in the question.

Comment: @ThomasRot Thank you.  That is the most clear description of this correspondence I have heard to date.  You should make it an answer and then think about writing a book.